# rails model querying returns 11 records but no limit is set

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, limit

I am querying a set of data using a custom model `Stat` based on `ActiveRecord`, using `sqlite3`. It is obvious that the total amount of data is more than 100, but when I do my querying of all data, it always returns 11 records, no more of other data, and I did not set any limit to the statement, but in console it just add a limit of 11. limit Below is my code:

```
2.5.1 001 > Stat.all

  Stat Load (2.1ms)  SELECT  "stat".* FROM "stat" LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 11]]

2.5.1 002 > Stat.count

  (0.4ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "stat"
>> 105
```

Is there any way to remove automatically added limit when I am doing this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Is your Rails version 5.1 or newer? Since 5.1, Rails only loads needed records.

To query all records from database, use `Stat.all.to_a` instead.

Note: this returns `Array` instead of `ActiveRecord_Relation`

See this PR: https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/28592

Comment: Does this mean that all the data has been retrieved, but only 10 are displayed at the terminal?

Comment: @weirdhoney Nope, it doesn't mean that, it only retrieve 11 records from db. To retrieve all records from db, do `Stat.all.to_a` instead.

Comment: get it, thanks for help, it seems that only `sqlite3` has such feature, i checked out to `postgresql`, it did load all the data.

Comment: I think it only works when you are inspecting data from console. So don't worry about it.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/21273811)

Comment: @SambhavSharma Thanks for the reminder, but I wasn't able to comment under questions until I got an upvote from this answer.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/21273811)

Comment: @Arvindraja I have updated my answer, thanks for the reviews guys!